# How are C declarations actually parsed, based on this interesting discrepancy?

Tags: c, parsing, initialization, language-lawyer, assignment-operator

It's fairly common to see a declaration and assignment combined like this:

```
int beans = a * 2;
```

or separate, like this

```
int beans;
beans = a * 2;
```

My current understanding is that beans can be assigned to because it is an lvalue; it has storage that can be written to. An rvalue, like `a * 2` cannot be assigned to since it's just an expression with a value, no storage. For this reason, this is allowed:

```
int beans;
(beans) = a * 2;
```

And in fact, any left operand to the assignment which is an lvalue should work. Now, this seems to suggest that `int beans;` is an expression which is also an lvalue. However, *this* is not allowed:

```
(int beans) = a * 2;
```

In terms of how the C parser is designed, this suggests that declarations are something greater than just an expression with an lvalue. What is going on here?

Comment: The `=` in `int beans = a * 2;` is not assignment at all. A declaration and an expression statement are just two completely separate grammar rules in the language. There isn't really anything to compare the way you are trying to.

Comment: You're saying that the = is an optional element of the declaration, instead of grammatically the same as an assignment as its own statement?

Comment: Yes, `=` just happens to be used as token in two different grammar productions, once in _init-declarators_ of _declarations_ and once as _assignment-operator_ in _assignment-expressions_.

Comment: That is called initialization: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization vs. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations

Comment: @AaronLinnell The optional `=` in a declaration introduces an initializer.  While there are similarities to an assignment, there are also many differences.  Among other things, you can initialize arrays, but you can't assign to them.  Try this:  `int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};`.  You can't do anything like that in an assignment.

Comment: `(int beans) = ...` isn't an expression, it is a syntax error. It's not particularly "interesting", it's just how the language syntax was designed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement

```
beans = a * 2;
```

contains many expressions.

The main expression is the assignment itself: `beans = a * 2`. That in turn contains two sub-expressions: `beans` and `a * 2`. The multiplication expression have sub-expressions itself: `a` and `2`.

All expressions can be parenthesized, which means the whole statement could look like this instead:

```
(beans) = ((a) * (2));
```

Here all the sub-expressions are parenthesized.

Now we come to the definition:

```
int beans;
```

That is *not* an expression. It doesn't contain any sub-expressions. It can not be parenthesized as a whole.

The definition with initialization, on the other hand:

```
int beans = a * 2;
```

*do* contain an expression, with sub-expressions. And that is on the *right* side of the `=`. So we can write it as:

```
int beans = ((a) * (2));
```

But again, the variable declaration part is not an expression, and can't be parenthesized.

---

Also please note that `=` in a definition is *not* assignment. It's *initialization*. There's a semantic difference indicated by the two different terms.

---

As mentioned in a comment by Jonathan Leffler. the *declarator* part of a declaration can be parenthesized.

For a simple declaration like

```
int beans;
```

it really makes no sense to use it. But for things like pointers to functions or pointers to arrays it makes a large difference.

Example:

```
int *foo(int x);
```

That declares a *function* that takes one `int` arguments and returns a pointer to `int`. Compare to the following:

```
int (*foo)(int x);
```

That declares a *variable*, which is a pointer to a function. The function takes one `int` argument, and returns an `int` value.

Comment: Note that you can include parentheses in the 'declarator': `int (beans);` or `int (beans) = 3;` — or even `int ((((beans)))) = { 3 };`  (you can include braces around the initializer for a scalar).  The relevant section of the standard is [§6.7.6 Declarators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6).